# How to add styles in Html.CheckBox control in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created the below checkbox list in cshtml:

```
if (control.ControlData == "1") {
                @Html.CheckBox(@control.ControlId, true, new { @id = @control.ControlId ,style="position:absolute;left: @string.Concat(@control.LeftLocation,"px"); top:@string.Concat(@control.TopLocation,"px");height:@string.Concat(@control.Height,"px")",@class="checkboxpair" });
        @*Basically want to replace the below by the above*@
                @*<input type="checkbox" style="position:absolute;left: @string.Concat(@control.LeftLocation+@control.Width/2,"px");top:@string.Concat(@control.TopLocation,"px");height:@string.Concat(@control.Height,"px")" class="checkboxpair" id="@control.ControlId" name="@control.ControlId" value="2" />*@
              }
```

I am getting some error related to :

> , expected

I think I am making a mistake while creating the html object inside `Html.Checkbox;` any idea on this?

Basically, how do I set styles for `Html.CheckBox` controls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `+` between variable names and string literals.

Where you have:

`style="blablablabla"px"blablablabla"`

should be

`style="blablablabla"+px+"blablablabla"`

and in your case:

```
@Html.CheckBox(@control.ControlId, true, new { 
    @id = @control.ControlId,
    @class="checkboxpair",
    style="position:absolute"
        + ";left:" + @string.Concat(@control.LeftLocation, px) 
        + ";top:" + @string.Concat(@control.TopLocation, px)
        + ";height:" + @string.Concat(@control.Height, px)        
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I am very close.I have done like this: